# TwentyTwelve versioning

Tags: css, child-theme

I'm making a child theme for TwentyTwelve, but my host is caching my files, so I'm not seeing the changes I do to my style.css file.

Is there a way to version the stylesheet for my child theme?

How is TwentyTwelve even adding the stylesheet? I don't see it in header.php.

Thanks

Comment: This question is not WordPress-specific (not even really WordPress-related). Please have a look at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: It is a WordPress question, since it's most likely something done in functions.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How it's **NOT** done in WordPress

The following example is the **opposite** of how one should do it. Bad practice following:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
/* ... Definitions that are hard to override or get rid off are here ... */
-->
</style>
```

This is another example how you should *not* do it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

### Do it right

WP uses a "dependencies" API for managing script and style files. This means that you

1. Register
2. Enqueue
3. (optionally, and for scripts only) Localize

This means that you first go and *register* a script for further usage and then enqueue it. This way you can *register* a stylesheet or script in your parent theme or plugin and later on enqueue it and print it to your webpage **on demand**.

### How to prevent caching

This API as well has one nice little argument for **versions**. This means, that you have a variety of options how to update your browser or server cache, as the version gets added to the query string when loading the file:

- *manually* add a new version string every time you write an update
- Using the `date()` or `time()` (or similar DateTime) functions to *permanently* update
- Use `filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory().'style.css' )` to **only change the version  when you did an update.
- And finally there's [the technique of "filename based cache busting"](https://gist.github.com/ocean90/1966227#file_fbcbfwss.php) that actually **alters the filename** if there were changes. It needs some `.htaccess` modifications as well.

### Example

This one's taken from a plugin I'm currently developing:

```
$file   = 'js/chained_selection.js';

wp_register_script(
     $this->handle
    ,plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).$file
    ,array( 'jquery',  )
    ,filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).$file )
    ,true
);
wp_enqueue_script( $this->handle );

wp_localize_script(
     $this->handle
    ,"{$this->handle}_obj"
    ,array(
         'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ,'nonce'   => wp_create_nonce( $this->ajax_nonce_val )
        ,'action'  => $this->action
    )
);
```

### **When** to load the stylesheet/script

Normally one simply wraps the register/enqueue/localize statements into a function or class method. To allow others jump in at the right point, the hooks used for **styles and scripts** are the following:

- `admin_enqueue_script` // Admin UI
- `wp_enqueue_script` // Themes
- `login_enqueue_script` // Login pages

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I did to fix it, is add a functions.php to my child-theme, and added the following:

```
<?php
function my_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/style.css', false, date('h:i:s'));
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'my_theme_styles');
```

So it loads the stylesheet twice, which is not ideal, but while the site is being developed, it helps keep the stylesheet fresh.

Comment: You need to edit `header.php` and remove the `<link>` to `style.css` to stop styles from being loaded twice

Comment: @bungeshea The styles aren't being loaded in header.php (like I said in my questions). They are being loaded in functions.php